# Marking path in my maze

Tags: c++

Im trying to mark the path through the maze. I'm stucked at this point. It only mark one way to the right. But the position when i write it out is X=1 Y=2. Its really strange. My idea was to make a while loop for the if statements but then the if statements not even run.. Please give me some ideas.

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-input") == 0)
{
    ifstream ifs(argv[2]);
    if(!ifs)
    {
        cout << "Felaktig textfil";
    }
    vector<vector<char>> maze;
    vector<vector<char>> path;
    string line;
    unsigned int j=0;
    while (!ifs.eof())
    {
        getline(ifs, line);
        maze.push_back(vector<char>());
        for (int i=0; i < line.size(); i++)
        {
            maze[j].push_back(line[i]);
        }
        j++;
    }
    //cout << maze.size();
    int startX,startY;

    for (int i = 0; i < maze.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < maze[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (maze[i][j] == 'S')
            {
                startX = j;
                startY = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (startX + 1 < maze.size() && maze[startX + 1][startY] != '*')
    {
        startX++;
        maze[startY][startX]='x';
    }

    if (startX - 1 > 0 && maze[startX - 1][startY] != '*')
    {
        startX++;
        maze[startY][startX] = 'x';
    }

    if (startY - 1 > 0 && maze[startX][startY - 1] != '*')
    {
        startY--;
        maze[startY][startX] = 'x';
    }
    if (startY + 1 < maze.size() && maze[startX][startY + 1] != '*')
    {
        startY++;
        maze[startY][startX]='x';
    }
    if (maze[startY][startX]=='X')
    {
        cout << "done";
    }
    cout << startX <<startY << endl;

    PrintMaze(maze);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what your question is and dont' understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is your question? What does your code do when you compile and run it and how does this differ from what you *want* it to do?

Comment: My code should mark the way from "S" the startposition. It is supposed to mark the way to X(exit). But it only moves from 0,1 to 1,2 and mark the way with small x. 0,1 is the start position that is saved in startX,startY. Nothing more happens, it never reaches the X.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? You can step through your code line by line and verify it does the same thing as your mental model indicates.

Comment: I have never used the debugger, dont know how it works actually. But dont you think I need some kind of loop outside the if statement so it will keep running? I just dont know how actually..

Comment: Time to learn. And let me assure you of something right now: If you think for even a moment you're "wasting time" learning to be effective with a debugger, you're *not*. You will easily spend over *half* your time on the business-end of a source-level debugger throughout your career. It easily tops the list of things they *should* teach you in academia, but rarely do, and frankly I think it borderline-**criminal** they take you're money and fail on even attempting to deliver such an important skill.

Comment: And an immediate side note: `while (!ifs.eof())` should be `while (std::getline(ifs, line))` and remove the `std::getline()` from inside the while-loop. As written you're going to improperly process a phantom-last-line, which I'm quite certain you do not want to do. `istream.eof()` is virtually **never** correct as a loop condition.

Comment: Craig's right about `getline`.  And as you say you need some kind of looping.  If you reach a dead end you need to be able to go back to the previous maze state where there was another path you could take.  There are a few ways you could do that - if you use a `std::vector<>` to store the x,y coordinates you've visited and which directions you've already tried from there, you can pop_back until you find an unexplored direction.  You can achieve something similar with recursion.

Comment: Tony D, very good answer, could you give me a code hint how i would store the path in the path vector? You mean just like cordinates?